# trying to open a wall, confused about lack of headers in existing openings

Tags: walls, framing

I'm looking to make an opening into what I think is a load bearing wall and I'm confused about the lack of headers on existing openings.

I made some sketches of my house floorplan to help explain my situation.

https://ibb.co/tzQDpHn

https://ibb.co/51fwQRY

https://ibb.co/8XGmWkg

my house is one of those "cape cod" houses. it's roughly 30 feet by 30 feet. built in 1950, canada.

it has a basement, a ground floor and an upper floor. the upper floor is one of those "half floors", I have one bedroom and a mezzanine and the roof starts to slant up after about 5 feet (straight vertical wall for about 5 feet then the roof angle starts). I also have an attic section that I can reach.

on the ground floor I have a staircase that goes up to the second floor and down to the basement. This staircase separates the living room from the kitchen. right now the opening to go down to the basement is in the kitchen and I want to move it to the other side in what I believe to be a load bearing wall.

the wall between the staircase and the kitchen (marked as wall 2) is not supported by a beam in the basement, so it's not load bearing (?) but it does support the ceiling of the kitchen and the attic space above it (which is empty).

question 1: doesn't the fact that this wall supports the ceiling of the room (about an 8 foot span) make it load bearing? those roof joists don't continue because the staircase is there, so on one end they are supported by this wall. but the existing opening in the kitchen wall to go to the basement doesn't have any thick header, at most it's a 2 times 2x4 header. I didn't open the wall but I knocked on the wall above the doorway and it's hollow. it's a 30" opening.

is a normal double top plate able to take the ceiling load for a 30" opening without requiring a header?

the wall between the living room and the staircase (wall #1) is supported by a beam in the basement. this wall has one existing opening between living room and the dining room. this opening is at least 4 feet wide. and again, wall above opening is hollow.

question 2: this wall, at this point, supports the floor joists of the second floor under the bedroom. again, I am assuming that this is load bearing, but why am I not finding a large header? is the double top plate of the wall and a 2 times 2x4 header enough to support the load of the floor in the middle of the house?

question 3: I want to make an opening, 30" wide, in this wall to replace the existing kitchen wall opening. at this point the wall only supports the half mezzanine floor above. if the wall supports the full floor at a different point with just a 2x4 header, I assume a normal 2 times 2x6 header would be sufficient for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Please use SE's built in image hosting facility. [Edit] your question, then either click the "Sun & Mountain" icon above the text edit box and paste in a link to the image, or just drag the image into the edit box. It'll be automatically uploaded & hosted and won't disappear in the future when a service dies or you decide to delete it to save space.

Comment: Technically a load bearing wall can sit on top of floor joists. The likelihood goes down as the wall approaches the joist centers. Search the internet for "transfer beam" to see instances of the pattern. It's unusual in US residential construction, new and old, but I can't say for Canada.

Comment: Have you verified that the ceiling joists run perpendicular to the missing headers? I would check each objectionable header instead of making any assumptions.